# Is there a CordovaWebView equivalent for Windows phone and Windows 8 applications?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows

I recently start working with Windows app using Apache Cordova Framework.

Cordova applications are usually implemented as a browser-based WebView within the native mobile platform. There are embedding WebViews for Amazon Fire OS, Android and iOS, and I can create my own WebView components that make full use of Cordova APIs. However, there is no Embedding WebView for Windows platform.

How can I embed a Cordova-enabled WebView component within my app so that I can take advantage of Cordova APIs?